# How to make showcase widget appear on top of text. I implemented it but its appearing beneath the text

Tags: flutter, dart, showcaseview

I am implementing a showcase widget but I want to place the widget on top of the text. How can I achieve this?
This is the code:

```
Showcase(
  key: keys,
  overlayOpacity: 0,
  overlayColor: Colors.transparent,
  title: "New!",
  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
  shapeBorder: const CircleBorder(),
  showcaseBackgroundColor: Color(0xfffcecaf),
  descTextStyle:
      const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13),
  description: "Tap to Learn more",
  child: Container(
    child: Text(
      "xyz",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        height: 1.2,
        color: AppColors.PRIMARY_COLOR,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```